# Find the index of the longest string and return that index?

Tags: python-3.x

I can use this to figure out what the longest string in the sequence is but how exactly can I find the index of the longest string. New to python btw, go easy on my pls.

```
     def longest_string(seq):
         max_list = max(seq,key=len)
         return max_list
     print(longest_string(["h","el","lo","worl","d"]))
     worl
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking the length only, use the `enumerate` method to get the position as well:

```
>>> seq = ["h","el","lo","worl","d"]
>>> max(enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
(3, 'worl')
```

Then you can just return the first item of the tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the assisstance.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> seq = ["h","el","lo","worl","d"]
>>> seq.index(max(seq))
3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answer. I wonder if you might improve your answer by adding a reference to what .index() does, to help the OP further. For example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-accessing-index-and-value-in-list/

Comment: This doesn't work... `max()` returns "worl" because "w" > "l',  not because it's the longest string.